# Aggregating and grouping Variables of a Variable in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with two Datasets: EU-KLEMS DATA and EMISSION Data. Both datasets include a classification of industries by EU NACE REV. 2 categories, however the classification in both datasets varies because of aggregation differences, I want to have the same classification in both datasets, in order to merge both datasets in another step.
Right now I have difficulties in modifying the classification of my emission dataset, let me introduce you to the code:
First, the **EU-KLEMS Dataset** with the following **NACE categories**:

```
unique(ga_DE_nace1$nace_r2_code)
 [1] "A"        "B"        "C"        "C10-C12"  "C13-C15"  "C16-C18"  "C19"      "C20"      "C20-C21" 
[10] "C21"      "C22-C23"  "C24-C25"  "C26"      "C26-C27"  "C27"      "C28"      "C29-C30"  "C31-C33" 
[19] "D"        "D-E"      "E"        "F"        "G"        "G45"      "G46"      "G47"      "H"       
[28] "H49"      "H50"      "H51"      "H52"      "H53"      "I"        "J"        "J58-J60"  "J61"     
[37] "J62-J63"  "K"        "L"        "L68A"     "M"        "M-N"      "MARKT"    "MARKTxAG" "N"       
[46] "O"        "O-Q"      "P"        "Q"        "Q86"      "Q87-Q88"  "R"        "R-S"      "S"       
[55] "T"        "TOT"      "TOT_IND"  "U"
```

Second, the **Emission dataset**:

```
glimpse(emissiondata)
Rows: 20,916
Columns: 7
**$ airpol**    <chr> "CH4_CO2E", "CH4_CO2E", "CH4_CO2E", "CH4_CO2E", "CH4_CO2E", "CH4_CO2E", 
**$ nace_r2**   <chr> "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
**$ unit**     <chr> "G_HAB", "G_HAB", "G_HAB", "G_HAB", "G_HAB", "G_HAB", "G_HAB", "G_HAB", 
**$ geo_code** <chr> "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", 
**$ year**     <int> 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 
**$ OBS_VALUE** <dbl> 473368.5400, 479522.4800, 461502.6900, 457124.3900, 444287.2400, 
**$ OBS_FLAG**  <chr> "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
```

with the following **NACE Categories**:

```
> unique(emissiondata$nace_r2)
 [1] "A"        "A01"      "A02"      "A03"      "B"        "C"        "C10-C12"  "C13-C15"  "C16"     
[10] "C17"      "C18"      "C19"      "C20"      "C21"      "C22"      "C23"      "C24"      "C25"     
[19] "C26"      "C27"      "C28"      "C29"      "C30"      "C31_C32"  "C33"      "D"        "E"       
[28] "E36"      "E37-E39"  "F"        "G"        "G45"      "G46"      "G47"      "H"        "H49"     
[37] "H50"      "H51"      "H52"      "H53"      "HH"       "HH_HEAT"  "HH_OTH"   "HH_TRA"   "I"       
[46] "J"        "J58"      "J59_J60"  "J61"      "J62_J63"  "K"        "K64"      "K65"      "K66"     
[55] "L"        "L68A"     "M"        "M69_M70"  "M71"      "M72"      "M73"      "M74_M75"  "N"       
[64] "N77"      "N78"      "N79"      "N80-N82"  "O"        "P"        "Q"        "Q86"      "Q87_Q88" 
[73] "R"        "R90-R92"  "R93"      "S"        "S94"      "S95"      "S96"      "T"        "TOTAL"   
[82] "TOTAL_HH" "U"
```

My reference categories are the ones provided in the EU Klems Dataset, so I want to have identical nace classification in both datasets (for that, I need to adjust my categories in the Emissions Dataset).

The Problem occurred in the line "#Here Things get tricky, towards the End of the code. I was expecting to get the sum of the emissions in all categories listet in c() of TOT_IND and MARKT. Instead I got 0. It is important that all categories that are included in the mutate function are in one Variable in the End. I hope you can help me! THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!:)

```
emissions_agg <- emissiondata %>%
  mutate(nace_r2_code = case_when(
    nace_r2  %in% c("A") ~ "A",
    nace_r2 %in% c("B") ~ "B",
    #C
    nace_r2 %in% c("C") ~ "C",
    nace_r2 %in% c("C10-C12") ~ "C10-C12",
    nace_r2 %in% c("C13-C15") ~ "C13-C15", 
    nace_r2 %in% c("C16", "C17", "C18") ~ "C16-C18",
    nace_r2 %in% c("C19") ~ "C19",
    nace_r2 %in% c("C20") ~ "C20",
    nace_r2 %in% c("C20", "C21") ~ "C20-C21",
    nace_r2 %in% c("C21") ~ "C21",
    nace_r2 %in% c("C22", "C23") ~ "C22-C23",
    nace_r2 %in% c("C24", "C25") ~ "C24-C25",
    nace_r2 %in% c("C26") ~ "C26",
    nace_r2 %in% c("C26", "C27") ~ "C26-C27",
    nace_r2 %in% c("C27") ~ "C27",
    nace_r2 %in% c("C28") ~ "C28",
    nace_r2 %in% c("C29", "C30") ~ "C29-C30",
    nace_r2 %in% c("C31", "C32", "C33") ~ "C31-C33",
    #D-F
    nace_r2 %in% c("D") ~ "D",
    nace_r2 %in% c("D", "E") ~ "D-E",
    nace_r2 %in% c("E") ~ "E",
    nace_r2 %in% c("F") ~ "F",
    #G
    nace_r2 %in% c("G") ~ "G",
    nace_r2 %in% c("G45") ~ "G45",
    nace_r2 %in% c("G46") ~ "G46",
    nace_r2 %in% c("G47") ~ "G47",
    #H
    nace_r2 %in% c("H") ~ "H",
    nace_r2 %in% c("H49") ~ "H49",
    nace_r2 %in% c("H50") ~ "H50",
    nace_r2 %in% c("H51") ~ "H51",
    nace_r2 %in% c("H52") ~ "H53",
    nace_r2 %in% c("H53") ~ "H53",    # was mit HH, HH_HEAT,...?
    #I
    nace_r2 %in% c("I") ~ "I",
    #J
    nace_r2 %in% c("J") ~ "J",
    nace_r2 %in% c("J58", "J59_J60") ~ "J58-J60",
    nace_r2 %in% c("J61") ~ "J61",
    nace_r2 %in% c("J62-J63") ~ "J62-J63",
    #K-P
    nace_r2 %in% c("K") ~ "K",
    nace_r2 %in% c("L") ~ "L",
    nace_r2 %in% c("L68A") ~ "L68A",
    nace_r2 %in% c("M") ~ "M",
    nace_r2 %in% c("M", "N") ~ "M-N",
    nace_r2 %in% c("N") ~ "N",
    nace_r2 %in% c("O") ~ "O",
    nace_r2 %in% c("O", "P", "Q") ~ "O-Q",
    nace_r2 %in% c("P") ~ "P",
    #Q-U
    nace_r2 %in% c("Q") ~ "Q",
    nace_r2 %in% c("Q86") ~ "Q86",
    nace_r2 %in% c("Q87_Q88") ~ "Q87-Q88",
    nace_r2 %in% c("R") ~ "R",
    nace_r2 %in% c("R", "S") ~ "R-S",
    nace_r2 %in% c("S") ~ "S",
    nace_r2 %in% c("T") ~ "T",
    nace_r2 %in% c("TOTAL") ~ "TOT",
    nace_r2 %in% c("U") ~ "U",
  # HERE THINGS GET TRICKY:
    nace_r2_ %in% c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M",
                    "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U" ) ~ "TOT_IND", # Total Industries (A-S)
    nace_r2_ %in% c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "M", "N","R", "S") ~ "MARKT", # all industries excluding L,O,P,Q,T, and U
    TRUE ~ NA
  )) %>%
    group_by(nace_r2_code, airpol, year, unit, geo_code) %>%
      summarise(OBS_VALUE = sum(OBS_VALUE, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
      filter(!is.na(nace_r2_code))
```

Comment: `case_when` checks conditions in order and takes the first one that is TRUE. So, when you have `nace_r2 %in% c("D") ~ "D", that will make all `"D"` values `"D"` results, and in your next condition you have `nace_r2 %in% c("D", "E") ~ "D-E"` the Ds are already set to `"D"` result, so this only sets all Es to `"D-E"` result. And then your next check `nace_r2 %in% c("E") ~ "E"` will never be met because all Es have already been set to `"D-E"` result.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do with the definition of `nace_r2_code`. You are creating it as a single column, which will have 1 value per row. But you are coding it as if you expect it to have many values per row. A `nace_r2` value of `"E"`, as explained above, will get a result of `"D-E"`. But you are writing conditions as if you expect it to get `"D-E"`, `"E"`, `"TOT_IND"`, and `"MARKT"`, all at the same time. This is not how `case_when` works, nor is it how columns generally work---1 value per row.

Comment: I would strongly suggest making a **minimal** example, with input of about 10-15 rows with 3 or 4 sample `nace_r2` values. Show what output you expect for that input, and we can help you get there. Then you can take what you learned on the small data and apply it to your full data.

Comment: You may find the `{forcats}` package useful in this context, and the `fct_recode()` function in particular.